# Web push FCM, tag in notification

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-cloud-messaging, service-worker

today (13.02.2018) my products are not working properly. I'm using them for notifications about incoming calls and applications in the servicedesk on the corporate portal.
I have a clear classification of notifications by tag. So I get notifications in the serviceworker:

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
    event.waitUntil(
        self.registration.pushManager.getSubscription().then(function(subscription) {
            if(event.data.json().notification.tag == 'Asterisk_Incomming'){
                if(typeof(event.data.json().data) == "undefined"){
                    return NotifyIncomming(event.data.json());
                }else {
                    return NotifyIncommingCall(event.data.json());
                }
            }else if(event.data.json().notification.tag == 'Asterisk_Queue'){
                return NotifyIncomming(event.data.json());
            }else if(event.data.json().notification.tag == 'Assistant_Notify'){
                return NotifyIncomming(event.data.json());
            }else if((event.data.json().notification.tag == 'Helpdesk_Notify') || (event.data.json().notification.tag == 'Helpdesk_Notify_Tech')){
                return NotifyHelpdesk(event.data.json());
            }else{
                return NotifyIncomming(event.data.json());
            }
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.error('Невозможно получить данные с сервера: ', err);
            })
    );  
});
```

Inside the event, I can get the data in `event.data.json()`
There will be 2 objects I need: `data`, `notification`
Previously, the notification object contained the tag parameter and I got it as `event.data.json().notification.tag`
But now tag is contained in the data (cite the full content of the object):

```
{gcm.notification.tag: "Helpdesk_Notify", channel: "36840"}
```

But the first object reference is invalid. Is this a bug or constant change? How can I get a tag from data?

i.e. I send JSON to https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send (using an authorization token) in the form:

```
{
"notification":{
    "body":"Статус заявки: ВЫПОЛНЕНА",
    "icon":"images/ManageEngine.jpg",
    "tag":"Helpdesk_Notify",
    "title":"Ваша заявка обновлена"
},
"data":{
    "channel":"36840"
},
"registration_ids": ["c4CfPHwLp7s:APA91bG3sf-0ua1RlhkcnTb6xuUWB46rg-grtdPfUYF7Ji8aw2awKTgRAoTP3CAiL-Fyjqk6FbwxOElV6qN8JQZIqLusiDed77OatEzj4Ae-hs3021wt2_gi4AeiRRnl3y6ToPBPY6em"]
}
```

Until 13.02.2018

I received the `notification` in
link: `event.data.json().notification`
form: `{title: "Ваша заявка обновлена", body: "Статус заявки: ВЫПОЛНЕНА", icon: "images/ManageEngine.jpg", tag: "Helpdesk_Notify"}`

I received the `data` in
link: `event.data.json().data`
form: `{channel: "36840"}`

After 13.02.2018

I received the `notification` in
form: `{title: "Ваша заявка обновлена", body: "Статус заявки: ВЫПОЛНЕНА", icon: "images/ManageEngine.jpg"}`

I received the `data` in
form: `{gcm.notification.tag: "Helpdesk_Notify", channel: "36840"}`

I can pass the tag as an additional parameter to the data, but I do not like this option.

Answer (score 0):

until I found nothing better than to transfer the tag to object `data` and, accordingly, to parse it (I had to provide an exceptional situation if object `data` was not received), in the end the query became of the form:

```
{
"notification":{
    "body":"Статус заявки: ВЫПОЛНЕНА",
    "icon":"images/ManageEngine.jpg",
    "tag":"Helpdesk_Notify",
    "title":"Ваша заявка обновлена"
},
"data":{
    "channel":"36840",
    "tag":"Helpdesk_Notify"
},
"registration_ids": ["c4CfPHwLp7s:APA91bG3sf-0ua1RlhkcnTb6xuUWB46rg-grtdPfUYF7Ji8aw2awKTgRAoTP3CAiL-Fyjqk6FbwxOElV6qN8JQZIqLusiDed77OatEzj4Ae-hs3021wt2_gi4AeiRRnl3y6ToPBPY6em"]
}
```

perhaps it makes sense to exclude a tag from the `notification` object, but I've

I get the tag by reference: `event.data.json().data.tag`
those. something like that:

```
if(typeof(event.data.json().data) == "undefined"){
    tag = 'StandartNotify';
}else {
    tag = event.data.json().data.tag;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it helps you: I have similar trouble with "tag" option at notifications payload, also at the same date as you. In my case, notifications are not being overridden on any device (notification have the same "tag").

I opened a ticket with their support and they recognize me that it was an error on their side (21 Feb).

They didn't tell me more, only stay alert to the release page.

https://firebase.google.com/support/releases